# Display array inside arrary loop

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, loops

I am working on a project where in I have tables of Invoices, Quotations and many more.

Where I am stuck is here -

I am saving values of quotation in to a table as a n array. Eg :-

If two services are selected then it saves it in this way : Service1, service2
Similarly its quantity and charges are saved in d same way:

```
 Sqty : 1,1
```

```
 Scharge: 100,300
```

Now For Invoice, I get the quotation id  and service name from POST

> ```
> $qdetails = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM tbl_quotation WHERE id ='$qid';") 
>  or die(mysql_error()); 
>   $qdet = mysql_fetch_array( $qdetails );
>   $pcharge = $qdet['pcharge'];
>   $scharge = $qdet['scharge'];
>   $pqty = $qdet['pqty'];
>   $sqty = $qdet['sqty'];
> ```

Then display the output in the following table -
 tbl_service_info is my table which has all the details of the service

```
<?php

foreach ($_POST['service'] as $key => $value) {


$query=("select * from tbl_service_info WHERE sname = '$value'");

$result=mysql_query($query) or die ("Unable to Make the Query:" . mysql_error() );

while($row=mysql_fetch_array($result)){
$product = @$row["sname"];
$prid = @$row["id"];
$sdetails = @$row["details"];
  ?> 
      <tr class="item-row">
          <td class="item-name"><div class="delete-wpr">
<textarea name="services[]"><?php echo $value ; ?></textarea></div></td>
          <td class="description"><textarea><?php echo $sdetails; ?></textarea></td>
          <td><textarea class="description"><?php echo $sunit; ?></textarea></td>
               <?php    } 
 $scharge1 = explode(",",$scharge);
foreach ($scharge1 as $keysc => $valuesc) {   ?>


          <td><textarea class="cost" name="scharge[]"> <?php     
 echo $valuesc;?> </textarea>  </td> <?php } ?>




 <?php     
 $sqty1 = explode(",",$sqty);

foreach ($sqty1 as $key2 => $value2) { ?>
          <td><textarea class="qty" name="snos[]"><?php echo $value2;?></textarea></td>
<?php } ?>

          <td><span class="price"></span></td>
      </tr>

       <?php } ?>
```

This is what i get.

http://oi61.tinypic.com/286v30j.jpg

[image]

The Unit Cost and Nos are not looping with the main loop.

Please help.
Also correct my question If I have written it the wrong way.

Thanks...

Comment: The image you posted seems to be showing nothing?

Comment: Nothing as in ? Product1(Panting) has unit cost of 100 which should come under unit cost and then product2(Texture paint) has unit cost of 300 which come under unit cost of product 2. Instead the loop is creating new <td>'s which are causing the duplication ...

Comment: What is the content of $charge ?

Comment: @ClémentMalet : $scharge = 100,300

Comment: @user1299086 Ok, then I'd say that your database model seems to be wrong. You have the values of the other products in the row of a distinct product. We could easily give you a workaround to have this code to work, but you'd better rework your database (or query at least), so that in a row you have only the values of the concerned row

Comment: @ClémentMalet : Really appreciate your help. first help me here so that alteast this code works and the project goes live for testing. Then I'll rework so that such issues wont arise..

Answer (score 0):

Following my comment, here is the workaround that should work in your case.

You can use a temporary value to echo the correct part of the exploded string ($charge)

```
$i = 0;
while($row=mysql_fetch_array($result)){

// Rest of your code

    $scharge1 = explode(",",$scharge);
    // Remove that foreach ($scharge1 as $keysc => $valuesc) {   ?> 
    <td><textarea class="cost" name="scharge[]"> 
      <?php echo $scharge1[$i];?>
    </textarea></td> 

// Rest of your code, also change the NOS part

    // Before the very end of your while loop, increment $i
    ++$i;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But its not working. Its just showing the first value of the array.

Comment: @user1299086 Did you add the `++$i;` at the end of your while loop ? It's that value which change the part of the exploded $charge to be displayed

Comment: An inner loop is missing between after the *explode* and until `++i`.

Comment: @ring0 : Can you please explain in detail which loop is missing and how should I add it ?